# Laravel 5.4 - Change URL name

Tags: laravel

So to start explaining things, I would first like to enumerate what I'm using.

I'm using **Laravel 5.4 and XAMPP.**

I want to deploy my project in a **localhost** only. So we're starting the project's server with `php artisan serve --host 192.168.254.11 --port 80` where the IP stated there is the IP of the server.

In that way, we have to type the url `192.168.254.11` to access the project. Is there any way to change that without getting an online server?

**EDIT:** I managed to change it with tweaking of `hosts` file. But for it to be possible to be accessed by the other users, they have to do the same. Is there a way to only change the hosts file of the server and still be accessible by other users at the same time?

Comment: you can put your ip to hosts file ?

Comment: I don't recall tweaking things in any hosts file. What is that? :o

Comment: search for changing hosts file linux/windows/osx

Comment: You could add a hostname to your local dns server. However if you want the name to be available online, you will have to buy a domain name.

Comment: Whatever my IP will be, that host name will be available for my localhost? Also for example, I'd like the url to be `myproject.exm`. 

That means I'll be running `php artisan serve --host myproject.exm --port 80`?

Comment: I somehow made it work, but I have some follow up questions. I edited my main post. Hope you guys can help me make sure if it's possible. :)

Comment: @Jerodev's comment is right - you are talking about mapping your local IP to a hostname that others on your network can access.  The best way to do that is add a DNS record in your DNS server.  How to do that depends entirely on your local network configuration, maybe your router supports it, maybe not, maybe your IT department run DNS servers, maybe not.  Another (poor) alternative is to manually add the record to everyone's hosts config.  That breaks if your IP ever changes.